# Is there a more accurate and guaranteed method to get Focal Length in 35mm in Android?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camerax

I am using exift data with "ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH_IN_35MM_FILM" to get Focal Length in 35mm on Android. However, TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH_IN_35MM_FILM data cannot be received for every android device in the exift data. In cases where I can get it (for example: on the s22 Ultra Wide Angle camera), the 35mm value comes as 13 data. And the people who commented on it say it was wrong.

```
 val exifInterface = ExifInterface("file")
 exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH_IN_35MM_FILM
```

Is 35mm focal length correct and is there a method that I can get for every device? Thanks